# pyfiglet, PyInstaller - compiling issues

Tags: python, compilation, pycharm, pyinstaller

I am writing a small, simple game to be played in the terminal window. Part of the game involves using pyfiglet’s fonts.

I’ve tried for many hours to get pyinstaller to compile it, however I’m always met with various errors. Namely, I believe the issue is pyinstaller not pulling the necessary information into the .exe and I get errors with all of the methods I’ve researched to date. I’m currently trying to compile with pyinstaller, using pycharm on a windows 10 laptop.

If I simply compile within pycharm using pyinstaller and then try to open the .exe by double clicking on it, a cmd window appears for a brief moment then disappears. When I go into a command terminal window and execute the program that way, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyfiglet_compile.py", line 50, in <module>
  File "pyfiglet_compile.py", line 8, in intro
  File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 65, in figlet_format
  File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 794, in __init__
  File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 801, in setFont
  File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
  File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 147, in preloadFont
pyfiglet.FontNotFound: banner3-d
[988] Failed to execute script 'pyfiglet_compile' due to unhandled exception!
```

Python 3.11.1 is the version I have on this machine.

Any idea how I can successfully tell pyinstaller to include the needed fonts ?

Multiple online variations of editing the spec file, adding hooks, adding extra instructions to the code. All attempts ended in errors, all of which refer to being unable to find the requested fonts.

I was/am hoping I can find a solution so I can run a standalone .exe with pyfiglet fonts on display. Given that pyfiglet isn't new, I'm surprised to see so many issues surrounding it being compiled.

Neat.

At any rate, here's some code I took off a youtube video that produces the same result - runs fine for me in pycharm, but when packaged with pyinstaller and double clicked, a black window appears briefly and disappears. The same errors above appear when running the .exe in a cmd window.

Below is code taken from a youtube video.

```
import sys
from pyfiglet import Figlet
import random

figlet = Figlet()

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    isRandomFont = True

elif len(sys.argv[1] == "-f" or sys.argv[1] == "--font"):
    isRandomFont = False

else:
    sys.exit(1)

msg = input("Input: ")

figlet.getFonts()

if isRandomFont == False:
    try:
        figlet.setFont(font=sys.argv[2])
        print(figlet.renderText(msg))
    except:
        print("Invalid usage")
        sys.exit(1)

else:
    font = random.choice(figlet.getFonts())
    print(figlet.renderText(msg))
```

Below is the output when ran in a cmd window:

```
C:\Users\...\Python_Projects\dist>test.exe
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 356, in get_provider
    KeyError: 'pyfiglet.fonts'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
      File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 794, in __init__
      File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 801, in setFont
      File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
      File "pyfiglet\__init__.py", line 136, in preloadFont
      File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1144, in resource_exists
      File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 358, in get_provider
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfiglet.fonts'
    [27176] Failed to execute script 'test.py' due to unhandled 
    exception!
```

Comment: python does  not compile. it is read by the interpreter line by line....  if you can provide the code, than maybe users can help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the pyinstaller isn't including parts of the pyfiglet package that are necessary for it to run.

You can either use the `--add-data` pyinstaller option to include each of the missing parts of the package to your executable, or an easier method would be to run.

```
pyinstaller -F --collect-all pyfiglet test.py
```

Comment: pyinstaller -F --collect-all pyfiglet test.py  
Produces an error

Comment: you run it in a terminal.... on the command line.

Comment: I did run it in a terminal, on the command line.